# How to split out image tags from a kustomize file in for deployment

Tags: kubernetes, release-management, kustomize

So I have the following `kustomize.yaml` file for my staging environment overlay and when I want to promote to production, I would like to move just the portion that has the image numbers into the production overlay. Ideally I would split out the images into a separate file called `versions.yaml`. I am not sure the best way to go about that. The container tag numbers are updated by the CI pipeline when a new container is created and pushed to the container repo.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: staging
namePrefix: stage-
commonLabels:
  app: xxx-staging
bases:
  - ./namespace.yaml
  - ./ingress.yaml
  - ../../../bases/container1
  - ../../../bases/container2
  - ../../../bases/container3
  - ../../../bases/container4
  - ../../../bases/container5
  - ../../../bases/container6
  - ../../../bases/container7
  - ../../../bases/container8
  - ../../../bases/container9
  - ../../../bases/container10
images:
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container1
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container2
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container3
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container4
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container5
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container6
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container7
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container8
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container9
    newTag: "1111"
  - name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/container10
    newTag: "1689"
```

Comment: Note that you're using deprecated syntax here (`bases` has been deprecated in favor of `resources` since at least 2020).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you could create a `kustomization.yaml` in your `production` overlay that (a) includes the `staging` overlay and then (b) has its own `images` section.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised about the syntax I will fix that. I think I have it solved now, I have created an env directory with a kustomize file for the top part of the ```kustomization.yaml``` and included that as a resource in the kustomize file above so its just that resource and the images, that way I can copy that one file to the production directory when I am ready to promote.